# Identify svn branch

Tags: svn, branch

How I can identify what svn **branch/tag** points my code?

I have project that is checked out from svn. It has svn metainfo, i.e **.svn** folders.
I want to know what svn path does my code point? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `svn info` in the working copy, it'll identify the repository URL for the directory. Since branches and tags are just directories in svn, you'll be able to tell which branch you're working with.